# Works perfectly up until the 6th page, and than bullets start appearing instead of images... Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have the following JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 for(var i=1; i <= 6; ++i){
    $('.etalage'+(i===1 ? '':i)).etalage({
        show_hint: false,
        thumb_image_width: 464,
        thumb_image_height: 464,
        source_image_width: 1000,
        source_image_height: 1000,
        zoom_element: '#custom_zoom_element'+(i===1 ? '':i),
        //source_image_height: 480,
        //source_image_width: 480,
        zoom_area_width: 400,
        zoom_area_height: 400
    });
 }
});
```

Which zooms into a large separate image when I hover over the thumbnail.  It works great for the first 5 images, but after that neither image shows up.  Here's one of the 6 essentially identical groupings of html:

```
<div>
<ul class="etalage">    
        <li>
            <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="codecanyon/demo_files/images/image2_thumb.jpg">
            <img class="etalage_source_image" src="codecanyon/demo_files/images/image2_large.jpg">
        </li>  
</ul>
```

```
<ul class="etalage2">   
        <li>
            <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="codecanyon/demo_files/images/image4_thumb.jpg">
            <img class="etalage_source_image" src="codecanyon/demo_files/images/image4_large.jpg">
        </li>  
</ul>
```

Another interesting thing to note is that on the 6th, 7th, etc. page a bullet from the  list-style-type shows up on each page.  Any ideas what mistake I'm making.  Thanks again.

Comment: Don't ask and read your code. It's the second line.

Comment: Why are your classes numbered?

Comment: This: i <= 6 ? I've increased that multiple times.  Still the same problem.  Image 6 is still always a bullet.

Comment: Then you're going to have to show us more than just your code... how about a demonstration of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set this up in your code to stop after 6 loops:

```
  for(var i=1; i <= 6; ++i){
```

Maybe you need to set `i <= 6` to a var and have this var count the number of .etalage's there are.

**edit**

so maybe:

```
var numberOfetalage = $('.etalage li').length

 for(var i=1; i <= numberOfetalage ; ++i){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your `for` loop. Change the following line:

```
for (var i=1; i <= 6; ++i)
```

change the `6` (`i <= 6;`) to whatever the amount of list elements you have.

e.g. I want 8 elements therefore my code is:

```
for (var i=1; i <= 8; i++)
```

Comment: No I've tried that multiple times.  It's the weirdest bug.  Even if I copy and paste the html code above, with no html error.  It'll work 5 consecutive times perfectly and on the 6th time they'll be a bullet instead of an image.

Comment: There are ghosts in the machine...